# Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly

Tags: wordpress

So I'm busy in Wordpress. I have a theme for the site and all. It's all working fine. Then I want to activate the new theme. BENG BENG, white screen of death. I debugged and this is the error:

```
Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2944
```

Line 2944 is just the line that throws an error. I already checked that.

Anyone ever experienced and solved this?

EDIT:

Referencing lines:

```
    function _doing_it_wrong( $function, $message, $version ) {

    do_action( 'doing_it_wrong_run', $function, $message, $version );

    // Allow plugin to filter the output error trigger
    if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'doing_it_wrong_trigger_error', true ) ) {
        $version = is_null( $version ) ? '' : sprintf( __( '(This message was added in version %s.)' ), $version );
        $message .= ' ' . __( 'Please see <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information.' );
        trigger_error( sprintf( __( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s' ), $function, $message, $version ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the line that the site is referencing?

Comment: Using `wp_enqueue_script()` incorrectly can't trigger a fatal error. On top of that, the error should only be shown when you have `WP_DEBUG` set to true. There must be something else that's wrong with the theme.

Answer (score 1):

The error have nothing related to the code you've added added. It is not a Wordpress core related issue, but an issue with your theme or a plugin

What the error means is that some script is enqueued way too early, ie, `wp_enqueue_script()` is hooked to a wrong hook that runs before `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `init`.

Unfortunately this error in Wordpress is a bit fague as it doesn't tell you exactly where the problem is, just that `wp_enqueue_script` is wrongly called.

You'll need to look for all instances in your theme and plugins for `wp_enqueue_script` and check that it is properly hooked

**EDIT**

From your comments, you have found three instances of `wp_enqueue_script`. You now need to see how it is hooked. It should look something like this

```
function some_function_name(){

   wp_enqueue_script(ALL THE SCRIPT DETAILS IN HERE);
}

add_action( 'THIS IS THE HOOK THAT IS IMPORTANT', 'some_function_name');
```

`THIS IS THE WRONG HOOK USED` is what you must check, as this is the wrong hook. This must be `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `admin_enqueue_scripts`, depending on if the script is meant for front end or back end

Comment: I have three files where `wp_enqueue_script` is coming up. How will I know if I have the right file, and what to change?

Comment: Now I get a white screen?

Answer (score 0):

In some of your plugins or your theme, a script may be included like this :

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

try to change it using this code:

```
<?php

function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', plugins_url('amazing_script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );  
?>
```