# Apache to Litespeed Wordpress Migration

Tags: wordpress, litespeed

I’m hoping I can find some help here. I have setup cyberpanel/litespeed and I’ve migrated my Wordpress site using Duplicator over from an Azure App Service (Apache based server). Since I’ve migrated over to Litespeed, I have been inundated with errors all over the site, most of them include these two:

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method …
Parse error : syntax error, unexpected ‘endforeach’ (T_ENDFOREACH)

Why would my site run seamlessy on Apache, but after migration all these errors are produced? Is there some kind of configuration I need to do?

Here are the server details:
Apache Server: PHP Version 7.4.26
Litespeed Server: PHP Version 7.4.29

Any help is appreciated.
Many thanks
Kahl

Comment: It's a syntax issue with PHP code. Is this from one of the plugins or themes? try to upgrade it or share the issue PHP code on your post.

Comment: It's not from a plug-in. The issue only occurs on the pages that I have coded.  

Here is an example:

1. This is a page from my site runnnig on Azure App Service (Linux, Apache, PHP 7.4.26) 
https://slabd.com.au/complete-through-dates/

2. I have cloned my site using duplicator and moved it here. This site is running CyberPanel (OpenLiteSpeed, PHP 7.4.29 (debugging is on)).  
https://cornerhost.com.au/complete-through-dates/

I have these issues on many pages, none of them exist on the orginal site.  I can only deduce it has something to do with OpenLiteSpeed?

Comment: If you open the console, there're many "Access to font at 'https://www.cornerhost.com.au/wp-content/themes/slabd-theme/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fa-solid-900.woff2' from origin 'https://cornerhost.com.au' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." issue. For the CORS issue, you need to address it from the origin server. Check https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/enable-cors-apache-web-server/

Comment: Thank you. Looking into it now.   Could the issue be because I'm not using an Apache server now, and previously I was?

Comment: Thank you - your advice has fixed the CORS problem.  However, the main issue still exists.

Comment: No problem. Yes, I do see the issue, it's PHP code related, easy to find other similar cases from google search, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137104/wp-enqueue-script-was-called-incorrectly and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804604/notice-wp-enqueue-script-was-called-incorrectly .  Please update all plugins to the latest version. If the issue is still showing, disable all plugins and switch to the default theme. It should be gone now. then enable each addon step by step, until the problem comes back. You know the source now.

Comment: i ended up resolving this issue by moving to an apache server